# PDO execute() throws error(42000)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to execute a prepared statement using PDO however I keep getting an error despite the fact that similar statements run fine in other files.

Here is the error I receive: `Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''merch'' at line 1 ) 1

Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
class Ben { 

    protected $_BTH;
    protected $_BTH;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_BBH = (---new PDO object---)
        $this->_BTH = $this->_BBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table");
    }
    my_function($table) {
        $this->_BTH->bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR); // table == merch
        $this->_BTH->debugDumpParams(); // outputs SQL: [20] SELECT * FROM :table Params: 1 Key: Name: [6] :table paramno=-1 name=[6] ":table" is_param=1 param_type=2
        $execResult = $this->_BTH->execute();

        if ($execResult == false) {
            die(print_r($this->_BTH->errorInfo())); // prints out the error I wrote earlier
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where the syntax error is, am I using any keywords? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: [You should have PDO throw exceptions on errors.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prepare a table's name. Nor you should. If your table's name comes somehow from user input, you should probably rethink your database structure.

Comment: Hi Truth, thanks for the quick answer. Just our of curiosity is this because not naming the table in the prepared statement removes the optimization that could take place? Also the table name varies depending on what I'm searching for not user input.

Comment: If it doesn't come from user input, and you're certain it is safe and doesn't contain anything evil, you can pass the variable directly.